# Technical analysis of Blockchain.info security breach

Tags: security

I the news I read this:

> The firm was forced to make a security disclosure on its blog and on
>   Reddit, admitting that a development error had led to a problem with
>   the generation of private keys. Private keys (effectively the private
>   addresses used to hold bitcoin) were generated with a low degree of
>   entropy, making them easy for attackers to retrieve.

Is there a detailed analysis available of what exactly happened or perhaps you could share your thoughts on this? I understand a concept of information entropy just want to know what should be done and what should be avoided to achieve a high degree of entropy.

Comment: What firm? Do you have a link to the article?

Comment: http://www.coindesk.com/blockchain-addresses-security-debacle-need-better/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen a thorough technical review. However, after reading about the issue, my understanding is that the issue related to reusing the same `k` nonce value for [ECDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm), not in generating private keys.

Blockchain.info's blog post about the issue is [here](http://blog.blockchain.com/2014/12/08/blockchain-info-security-disclosure/).

Blockchain.info's GitHub commit that fixed the issue is [here](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet/commit/98d5a7ca59ef04d06ac6aee468634b12975a0f5c).

The individual who noticed its effect on transactions is a forum user by the name of "johoe" and you can see the discussion that unfolded beginning with [this post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=581411.msg9774894#msg9774894).

It is a known requirement for ECDSA that for each signature with a particular private key, a unique `k` value must be used, otherwise with even just two signatures of the same `k` the private key used in the signature can be recovered. This issue is described in depth [here](http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/19/dsa-requirements-for-random-k-value/).

[Here](https://github.com/filosottile/blockchainr) is an open source project that discovers vulnerable private keys on the blockchain. [This slide show](https://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2014kul/materials/D1T1%20-%20Filippo%20Valsorda%20-%20Exploiting%20ECDSA%20Failures%20in%20the%20Bitcoin%20Blockchain.pdf) discusses the issue, the open source project, and some investigation into which wallets are susceptible (Blockchain.info is among the unsafe ones listed).

The solution for this has been known for a while: use [RFC 6979](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6979.txt).